# How to color the asterix first character in a p tag

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I thought this would be easy using the `::first-letter` pseudo element but it doesn't work!

I have

```
<p>* Required Fields</p>
```

and I want the * to be red!

Any ideas?  Note I can't change the html.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ducS/

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using a `li` element ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a very useful description of the problem.  Is it a specific browser that's a problem?

Comment: Weird: http://jsfiddle.net/TBAaE/

Comment: Do you really want *all* of your `p` tagged elements in the HTML page to have first letter red? If not, what criteria do you have to distinguish this one from the others?

Comment: Just as some additional info, it's asterisk* not asterix.

Comment: ***Interesting.....*** http://jsfiddle.net/TBAaE/4/

Comment: [The first letter of an element is not necessarily trivial to identify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3A%3Afirst-letter)

Comment: Note that it also bug with question mark, exclamation, comma, dot, ...

Comment: For what it's worth, Opera12 and IE9 only color the asterisk red.  Chrome picks the asterisk plus the next character, Firefox appears to color nothing.

Comment: Definitely , "Question Of The Day"!

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific.  I do have classes I can target the actual elements I want.  If I put a letter before the *, then that's coloured.  But the asterix itself is ignored.

Answer (score 9):

I *almost* have a solution (well, you might see it as a solution) and it works with your HTML :

```
p::before {
    content:'*';
    position:absolute;
    color: red;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px red;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/mN6jW/)

I launched a virtual machine to test on IE, it looks good :

[image]

Comment: Very creative solution. Likely the only one possible - I just went through the whole [level 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) which contains a long list of all the selectors from levels (1-4), not possible in any of those. Maybe in an extension some day.

Comment: @Neal The difference is my solution works with OP HTML. The absolute positioning made the * being drawn at the same position.

Comment: I was just working on doing the same thing with position: relative, but this is better.

Comment: We can still see the black asterisk under the red one. I'm on chrome 28.

Comment: I was working a similar riff, using visibility hidden on :first-line and before / after to recreate the line. The elements could be styled independently and should solve the issue of the "shine through" on chrome 28. http://jsfiddle.net/NkapN/

Comment: @Brewal Hence the "almost".

Comment: My solution is also a pretty big hack, but seems to display the same in Firefox 22, Safari 6.0.4, and Chrome 28.0.1500.71. Sorry, I don't have IE to test.

Comment: Yes I understood it this way too, but you haven't said it :)

Comment: @Benjamin: If there's any change to the Selectors spec it would be to `::first-letter`, but I doubt that it will change at all. If a new pseudo-element is introduced it'll probably be outside Selectors.

Comment: What about a 1px red drop shadow to make sure we don't see any black ?

Comment: @Brewal it's a little better on Chrome, yes. I added that to my answer.

Comment: @AndrewClody I like this solution as I'd hope it wouldn't be browser-specific and only one lot of text is displayed.  But what a palava to do something that I thought would be trivial!

Comment: @PedroKTFC What you do isn't really standard, to be honest. A problem is that your HTML is far from semantic. The starting * is an element of decoration and should have been done otherwise (with a list item, or with a ::before). That's one of the reason it's hard to do. Another one is that elements are supposed to be homogeneous, you shouldn't split them in CSS generally.

Comment: @dystroy I'd agree with you but the problem is I don't have much control over the html.  In some places the asterisk is in an <em> tag which makes it much easier to handle.

Comment: @PedroKTFC I got that, hence my answer. I wasn't criticizing you but just trying to explain why it's hard : it's because it's not the right way ;)