# How to put * asterisk to the right side in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I got stuck in this simple task. I've spent 6 hours in searching solution for this over the internet but can't get anything.

Please visit this url https://direct.studentlingo.com/cart/checkout

[image]

I think you got that what I want to do.

Please help me!!!

Comment: Not sure about drupal but alternatively you can also do it using [CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197671/use-css-to-automatically-add-required-field-asterisk-to-form-inputs)

Comment: Please, add more detail about which ecommerce module is using this site. It seems that is using Ubercart.

Comment: Yes I'm using Ubercart in drupal 7.2

Comment: Asterixes are treated rather differently, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835638/how-to-color-the-asterix-first-character-in-a-p-tag for some discussion about them. It might help steer you. If you don't do it in css, you'll have to modify the relevant .tpl file.